# Behat3 redirect within custom step

Tags: behat

I am trying to redirect to a url from within a custom step. That was doable on behat 2.x via:

```
return new Step\Then("my/url/page");
```

Unfortunately you can not call external steps from within your custom steps in behat 3.0!

How can I perform a redirect in my custom step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step chaining was removed from Behat 3 as it's considered a bad practice.

As [explained by everzet](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/behat/Gjb1iSxE_c4/kSe3_mpZ_G8J):

> Use the code tools like abstraction, compositions and inheritance together with a simple method calls :) Chained steps was an anti-pattern. It was hard to debug and maintain them. And in most cases, what could be done with 2-3 chained steps could be done with 1-2 method calls.

And [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/behat/QErnGjHNczU/B7aTGDR_GfUJ):

> Because as soon as you start doing that you:
>
> 1. Can not refactor your contexts
> 2. Can not clearly see what the code actually does
> 3. Can not easily reword your features
>
> And if you think that using inline steps is easier:

```
return array(
    new Step\Given(‘I am on the homepage’),
    new Step\When(‘I follow ”Login”’),
    new Step\When(‘I fill ”Username” with “‘ . $username . '"’),
    new Step\When(‘I fill ”Password” with “‘ . $password . '"’),
    new Step\When(‘I click “Login"’),
);
```

> It is not:

```
$session = $this->getSession();
$page = $session->getPage();

$session->visit($this->locateUrl(‘/‘));
$page->clickLink(‘Login’);
$page->fillField(‘Username’, $username);
$page->fillField(‘Password’, $password);
$page->pressButton(‘Login’);
```

Also see https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/546

There's an extension for Behat 3 with step chaining implementation, but it is broken and it's unlikely it'll be ever officially supported: https://github.com/Behat/ChainedStepsExtension

**Solution**

To solve your problem you can extend the [`Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext`](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/RawMinkContext.php) and use it to access the session:

```
$this->getSession()->visitPath('my/url/page');
```

You could also look at [the page object extension](https://github.com/sensiolabs/BehatPageObjectExtension).